# How do i get total value of scores in the table?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Student Name</th>
    <th>Student Score</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown" onchange="showScore()">
        <option> - </option>
        <option id="StudentA"> Student A </option>
        <option id="StudentB"> Student B </option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown" onchange="showScore()">
        <option> - </option>
        <option id="StudentA"> Student A </option>
        <option id="StudentB"> Student B </option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
const data = {
  "students": [{
    "studentName": "studentA",
    "studentScore": "60"
  }, {
    "studentName": "studentB",
    "studentScore": "50"
  }, ]
}

function showScore() {
  const dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('#dropdown')
  dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => {
    const selectedVal = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].id
    const formattedVal = selectedVal.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + selectedVal.slice(1)
    const score = data.students.map(item => {
      if (item.studentName == formattedVal) {
        dropdown.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].innerText = item.studentScore;
      }
    })
  })
}
```

How do i automatically get the value of total scores of each student? and also how do move the  const data into php and make it hidden and call in the function using ajax? thank you for helping me.

Comment: As mentioned yesterday, you have duplicate `id` attributes (`id="dropdown"`). This is invalid, `id`s need to be _unique_!

Comment: hi bro like i said, the code works perfectly, right now i have an issue with the student score which im not sure how to add them up

Comment: That doesn't make it a valid document though. `id="StudentA"` and `id="StudentB"` are also duplicate. Run a validator on that code, it'll come up with various "_Duplicate ID_" **errors**. Just an fyi.

Comment: thanks for the headsup, do u know how to do the calculations?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why is this question tagged with PHP, but does not contain any such code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments above, it would be recommended to ensure each ID is unique and maybe use value instead to ID in the selects.

You can make use of the `querySelectorAll` attribute to map over the information and get the total scores using a `[data-score]` attribute on the table column.

See my changes to allow for this

```js
const data = {
  "students": [{
    "studentName": "studentA",
    "studentScore": "60"
  }, {
    "studentName": "studentB",
    "studentScore": "50"
  }, ]
}

function showScore() {
  const dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('#dropdown')
  dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => {
    const selectedVal = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].id
    const formattedVal = selectedVal.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + selectedVal.slice(1)
    const score = data.students.map(item => {
      if (item.studentName == formattedVal) {
        dropdown.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].innerText = item.studentScore;
      }
    })
  })
  
  // Sum total score
  let scores = document.querySelectorAll("[data-score]")
  let scoresInt = [...scores].map(item => parseInt(item.textContent) || 0)
  let sum = scoresInt.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
  document.querySelector("#totalScore").innerHTML = sum
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Student Name</th>
    <th>Student Score</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown" onchange="showScore()">
        <option> - </option>
        <option id="StudentA"> Student A </option>
        <option id="StudentB"> Student B </option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td data-score></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown" onchange="showScore()">
        <option> - </option>
        <option id="StudentA"> Student A </option>
        <option id="StudentB"> Student B </option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td data-score></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div>
Total Score
</div>
<div id="totalScore">0</div>
```

I created a few variables to get the instances of all scores, then use the ES6 reduce method to accumulate these and set that value into the div for total scores.

Answer (score 0):

The Array.prototype.reduce() method is best suited for operations like this (sum total).

```
const sumTotal = arr =>
  arr.reduce((sum, { price, quantity }) => sum + price * quantity, 0)

const data = [
  { id: 1, price: 30, quantity: 2 },
  { id: 2, price: 20, quantity: 4 },
  { id: 3, price: 10, quantity: 2 },
]

const total = sumTotal(data);
```